# Exportar de access a excel en dos pestañas

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quiero exportar de access a excel en xlsx, dos tablas en dos pestañas distintas y ponerle un nombre a cada pestaña.

Si hago algo como esto:

```
Private Sub Comando0_Click()
 
 
Dim miExcel As String
 
 
miExcel = "C:\Desktop\ExportarExcel.xlsx"
 
 
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Tabla1", miExcel, True
 
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Tabla2", miExcel, True
 
 
MsgBox "Exportación realizada correctamente", vbInformation, "OK"
 
End Sub
```

No puedo abrirlo en xlsx. Me da error. Tengo que guardarlo con otra extension para poder abrirlo.

Si hago:

```
Private Sub Comando0_Click()
 
Dim miExcel As String
 
miExcel = "C:\Desktop\ExportarExcel.xlsx"
 
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "Tabla1", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", miExcel
 
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "Tabla2", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", miExcel
 
End Sub
```

Puedo abrirlo en xlsx pero solo se me graba una tabla, no las dos.

No sé cómo es para guardarlo en dos pestañas distintas, y ponerle un nombre especifico a cada pestaña.

Tengo el office professional plus 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu primera opción es la mejor, pero debes hacer algunos ajustes dado que estás usando un tipo de archivo de Excel recomendado para versiones de hace varios años:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Tabla1", miExcel, True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Tabla2", miExcel, True
```

Prueba así y comentas. Saludos.

Comment: Ahora sí. Gracias!